# Cannot use tab key validation in keydown event

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub cb_item_name_panel_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cb_item_name_panel.KeyDown

   If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then

            If cb_item_name_panel.Text <> String.Empty Then
                cb_sku_name.Text = cb_item_name_panel.Text
                item_panel.Visible = False
                cb_sku_name.Focus()
            End If
        End If
        
    End Sub
```

If I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, code working fine, but if I press <kbd>tab</kbd> code not executed. What's wrong with it?